# Add Account in Outlook 2011 is greyed out

Tags: ms-office

I try to add a new email account to Outlook 2011 for Mac. On the "Enter your account information" sheet the "Add Account" button is greyed out (only the Cancel button is visible). I cannot add a directory service or exchange account, I cannot add anything :-) Everytime the the "Add" button is greyed out :-(

The two screenshots show the problem: the button to add a new account is disabled (even if I fill in all the values).

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**: it depends on the provided email address... If I use an email address with subdomain, it does not work or rather the button is disabled.

Comment: can you edit your post and add a screenshot of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I provide an email address without subdomain, enter the imap server manually and after that change the email address to the correct one it is working ^^

Answer (score 0):

Odd. Not really an answer, but all I can say is that it works for me. As far as I'm aware I don't have any other specific Outlook configuration that deviates from a "standard" install. Once you've filled out all the relevant information in the edit fields (which I did in order from top to bottom and with "valid" information), the "Add Account" button becomes un-greyed. Like so:

[image]

Comment: Even if I fill in legal information, it is still disabled...

Answer (score 0):

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/outlook-2011-mac-add-account-button-disabled/f2ed9daa-ec48-4a67-89d9-06861c57bfbb

"This indicates corruption. We had a script in Entourage that helped to find the folder with a problem, but the script is broken in Outlook."